# Cors Auth SpringBoot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors, token

i am working with springboot and angular.
Try Login with JWT, when send the http with postman the request is ok but when Try send the same http with Angular i got the next error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
> HTTP ok status.

and

> zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST http://localhost:8080/login
> net::ERR_FAILED

when I send requests other than login they work fine
I understand that need a cors so the code is the next:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().cors();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration configuration = new org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

but the error is the same.

Comment: Sure, because your BE with spring boot is different origin with angular. You can set your ```proxy.conf.json``` in your angular app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proxy.conf.json in your angular app.

This is the example `proxy.conf.json`

```
{
  "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api" : ""
      }
  }
}
```

Then you can hit your BE using `http://localhost:4200/api/path-be`

`http://localhost:4200` is your angular app.
`/api` if you make request to `/api/*` so the angular proxy config will redirect to BE that you define in `proxy.conf.json`

Remember to add `proxy.conf.json` to your `angular.json`

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-hands-on:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
```

Restart your angular app

Comment: Thanks !!! NOTE:  I add "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json", on package.json and run the project with NPM START and not with NG SERVE

Comment: Very gratefull if it can help.